# Eulerian graph from vertex subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $K_{n1,n2,...,n\ell}$, where $\ell \geq 3$, denote a graph for which the vertex set is partitioned into $\ell$ subsets of respective size $n_1, n_2, ..., n_\ell$ and any two vertices are adjacent if and only if they do not lie in the same subset. Find conditions that characterize when $K_{n1,n2,...,n\ell}$ will be Eulerian?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: You know that $K_{n_1,\ldots,n_\ell}$ is Eulerian precisely when each of its vertices has even degree. For $k=1,\ldots,\ell$ let $V_k$ be the set of vertices of size $n_k$, and let $V=\bigcup_{k=1}^\ell V_k$. Let $n=|V|$. Each vertex $v\in V_k$ is adjacent to every vertex in $V\setminus V_k$ and to no vertex in $V_k$, so

$$\deg v=|V\setminus V_k|=n-n_k\;.$$

Thus, we need $n-n_k$ to be even for $k=1,\ldots,\ell$. This will certainly be the case if all of the numbers $n_k$ are even, but there are other possibilities that need to be investigated.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Though, a few things that stuck in my mind. For the following union, $V=\bigcup_{k=1}^nV_k$, doesn't it need to be up to $\ell$ instead of up to $n$? And the second thing, when it says in the problem "any two vertices are adjacent iff ...", does it mean like you have specified, each vertex from subset $V_k$ is adjacent to 'every' other vertex in $V \setminus V_k$? That part of the question sounds a bit vague to me. I thought it meant two vertices 'can be' adjacent only if they lie in separate subsets, but it doesn't mean that all of them 'must' be adjacent.

Comment: @portal: Yes, the upper limit of the union was a typo for $\ell$. And yes, each vertex in $V_k$ is adjacent to *every* vertex in $V\setminus V_k$. That’s exactly what *two vertices are adjacent if and only if they do not lie in the same subset* means. They are adjacent if they do not lie in the same subset, so each vertex in $V_k$ is adjacent to *every* vertex in $V\setminus V_k$, and they are adjacent *only* if they do not lie in the same subset, so no two vertices of any $V_k$ are adjacent.

Comment: Well, if all of the numbers $n_k$ are odd, then the sum $n$ will be even, but then if we do $n - n_k$, we will get an odd number. One possibility is if both $n$ and all $n_k$ are odd, but I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: @portal: Right. If $n$ is odd, then $n-n_k$ is even if and only if $n_k$ is odd. That means that $\ell$ must be odd; why? And such a graph is certainly possible: $K_3$ is exactly the same graph as $K_{1,1,1}$ for instance.

Comment: If $\ell$ is odd, we will have odd number of subsets, but I don't know how this will help us? And when you say $K_3$ is the same graph as $K_{1,1,1}$, you mean something like isomorphism, or just in the sense of this problem, because of the subsets?

Comment: @portal: Draw $K_3$ and $K_{1,1,1}$; if you do it correctly, you won’t see any difference.

Comment: Well, $K_3$ is a triangle, and $K_1$ is just a vertex without any edges, so $K_{1,1,1}$ won't be just 3 vertices without edges? Or I have to connect them? On the other hand, I still don't see how having odd number of subsets helps.

Comment: @portal: Go back to the definition of $K_{n_1,\ldots,n_\ell}$: each vertex of each part is adjacent to every vertex of every other part. $K_{1,1,1}$ is a triangle: the vertex in the first part is connected to the vertex in the second part and the vertex in the third part, and the vertices in the second and third parts are connected to each other.

Comment: Ops, that $K$ confused me, I was thinking about complete graphs. Yes, according to the definition, what you suggest works, and I will not see any difference between the two graphs. But still having trouble to generalize this. I know that either all $n_k$ must be even, so that $n$ will be even and their difference will be even. Or all $n_k$ need to be odd, in which case $n$ must also be odd.

Comment: @portal: You’ve essentially solved the problem: either all $n_k$ are even, or all $n_k$ are odd, and in the latter case $\ell$ must also be odd. Every such combination of $n_k$s and $\ell$ works, and no other combinations work.

Comment: Yes, not I see the role of $\ell$ being odd. Thanks!

Comment: @portal: You’re welcome!